# National holiday web service

Tags: web-services, egovernment

Is there a public/government web service that I can call to find out what the national holidays are for a given year? (For the US and/or any country in the world.)

Edit: Does anybody have a set of formulas to calculate US holidays? (C# would be my language of choice if there is a choice.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a web service at http://www.holidaywebservice.com which will provide dates of holidays for the USA, Republic of Ireland, England and Scotland. They also sell a DLL and source code.

As for details of algorithms, you could do worse than check out the excellent [Calendrical Calculations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521702380) book (third edition), which is a really fascinating read for all matters calendrical, and includes sample LISP code for their calendar algorithms.

Comment: Cool service and references, but my problem is trying to find a up-to-date source of which holidays are official U.S. government holidays (as in, the feds aren't at work on those days).

Comment: Interesting site, but it's so horribly designed (my eyes bled), and it doesn't have anything like isHoliday(date).

Comment: I also searched for such a webservice few days ago and i found [this](http://www.holidaycalendarservice.com/) very promising holiday calendar web service. I think it is worth a try :)

Comment: @funcoder - The site you provide appears to be for an API that is not yet available.  Given how long ago that was, I'm guessing there won't be a final product available

Comment: service:

http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/USHolidayService.asmx/GetHolidaysForYear?year=2015

Documentation:
http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/USHolidayService.asmx?op=GetHolidaysForYear

Comment: holidaywebservice is gone... All links are broken.

Comment: Just want to let you know this service is no more available on internet.

Answer (score 16):

You can try https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/. Enrico Service is a free service providing public holidays for several countries including US. Public holidays for the countries like US or Germany are provided separately for each state. You can use either json or soap to get public holidays from Enrico.

Comment: This worked for me. This is awesome.

Answer (score 6):

There are online calendars you can subscribe to.  For example, Google provides US Holidays:

[ICAL](http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)
[HTML](http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Los_Angeles)

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of similar information that really should be provided by government web services. It would certainly save a lot of money and errors in the long run if the U.S. Government could provide information like this through web services. Heck, even having it in a downloadable, parseable format would be a big step in the right direction.

I ran across this question while looking for a way to ensure an application skipped all U.S. Federal holidays in working days calculations. The best .gov source I found is:

[Operating Status Schedules from OPM](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/)

This has the data we need through 2020, but we'll have to type it into our own tables.

Comment: OPM has a new URL
https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays

Answer (score 2):

No one gives that up for free (any country in the world?  Get real).  The best source is Copp Clark (I'm unaffiliated).  They provide all holidays for all countries broken down by financial market, currency, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some parsing may be required, and it's not 100% complete, but you can use [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country).

Answer (score 1):

For the method/assembly to figure out US Holidays, basically just figure out all the major holidays and the "formula" that they use.

For the ones that never change, like Christmas, it's easy - December 25th.

For the ones that do change somewhat, there's usually a formula - like the third Monday in February being Presidents Day. You can just have the method figure this out for a given year.

This won't work for holidays without any particular pattern (i.e., some committee decides what the date is every year) but for all the major ones there's easily discernible formulas.

This would actually be a great candidate for Test Driven Design. You will know all of the major holiday dates for a particular year, so you should be able to feed that year into the method and get the right answers.

Comment: Just be careful...the US Federal Holiday for Christmas is NOT always December 25.  If that date falls on a weekend, the holiday is the closer of Friday or Monday.  Likewise for Veterans Day and Independence Day.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for something similar PL/SQL based. I found jollyday (sourceforge). It is java maybe you can use it with ikvm from c#. Sadly I was not able to load the java api into my oracle rdbms ... so ... if you came across a pure C or PL/SQL solution, please let me know :-)

Cheers 
Chris

Comment: Just a link to make it easier to find: http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/ and https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday (sourcecode).

Comment: Agreed  Dec 26 2016 is observed as holiday

Comment: Here is a C# Project https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date a JSON API is also available